# Change Page Title Dynamically AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Below is my code,
i need to change the maintitle dynamically in h2 tag on click of navigation (navlinks) through angularJS.

Thanks in advance..

```js
var portfolioApp = angular.module('portfolioApp', []);   

portfolioApp.controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {

    $scope.navLinks = [{
        Title: 'home',
        LinkText: 'Home'
    }, {
        Title: 'about',
        LinkText: 'About Us'
    }, {
        Title: 'portfolio',
        LinkText: 'Portfolio'
    }, {
        Title: 'contact',
        LinkText: 'Contact Us'
    }];

    $scope.navClass = function (page) {
        var currentRoute = $location.path().substring(1) || 'home';
        return page === currentRoute ? 'active' : '';
    };   

$scope.maintitle = "Any Title";

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="portfolioApp" ng-controller="navCtrl">
<h2>{{maintitle}}</h2>
<header class="well sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li ng-repeat="navLink in navLinks" ng-class="navClass('{{navLink.Title}}')">
            <a href='#/{{navLink.Title}}'>{{navLink.LinkText}}</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
  </div>
```

Comment: Simplest way; inject `$rootScope` and set `$rootScope.maintitle`

Comment: can you get me a code example.

Comment: @Phil 's way is good too but i edited the snippet the work the way i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Out This:

```js
var portfolioApp = angular.module('portfolioApp', []);   

portfolioApp.controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
$scope.maintitle = "Some Thing";
    $scope.navLinks = [{
        Title: 'home',
        LinkText: 'Home'
    }, {
        Title: 'about',
        LinkText: 'About Us'
    }, {
        Title: 'portfolio',
        LinkText: 'Portfolio'
    }, {
        Title: 'contact',
        LinkText: 'Contact Us'
    }];

    $scope.navClass = function (page) {
        var currentRoute = $location.path().substring(1) || 'home';
        return page === currentRoute ? 'active' : '';
    };
  $scope.goToLink = function(navlink){
    $scope.maintitle = navlink.Title;
    // fix location service accordin to your requirment
    $location.path(navlink.Title);
  }

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="portfolioApp">
<header class="well sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-list" ng-controller="navCtrl">
      <h2>{{maintitle}}</h2>

        <li ng-repeat="navLink in navLinks" ng-class="navClass('{{navLink.Title}}')">
            <a ng-click="goToLink(navLink)">{{navLink.LinkText}}</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome Tell me if you need more help!

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-app="portfolioApp">
<div ng-controller="navCtrl">
<h2>{{maintitle}}</h2>
<header class="well sidebar-nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-list" >
        <li ng-repeat="navLink in navLinks" ng-class="navClass('{{navLink.Title}}')">
            <a href='#/{{navLink.Title}}'>{{navLink.LinkText}}</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
<div>
</div>
```

and use

```
$scope.maintitle = 'title'
```

Comment: how would the maintitle change dynamically on click of the navlinks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.maintitle = "text you want";
```

EDIT: It won't work since it is out of controller. I can advise carrying it into controller, making another controller or searching for ways of manipulating items that are out of controller.

Comment: That is out of the scope of the controller, you have to put the h2 inside the controller scope.

Comment: i need dynamically on click of the navigation the h2 main title should change.

Comment: @barha 's answer will work. get the h2 element inside controller.